# In R, using the rgl package, can I change the window title?

Tags: r, rgl

I tried to find in the documentation how to change the window title but without success. Is it possible to set the window title in any way? By default, my window are titled like so `"RGL device 1 [Focus]"`.

Comment: Thank you! Please post an answer to deem it the right answer.